# Dynamically adding words to a char *

Tags: c, pointers, memory, char, scanf

I am having trouble figuring out how to read in words from stdin and store them in a pointer.  I need to expand the memory required as I go, so that I use the minimum amount of memory required.

Here's how I did it with ints, but with chars it's a bit harder.

```
int *expand(int *source, int size)
{
  int *expansion = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<size-1; i++)
    {
      expansion[i] = source[i];
    }
  free(source);
  return expansion;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  int *input = (int *)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
  int size = 3;//start at 3 because that's initial size
  int count = 0;//position in array
  fprintf(stdout, "Enter some numbers, and press 0 when you are done.\n");

  int *temp;

  while (1)
    {
      fscanf(stdin, "%d", temp);
      if (*temp == 0)
        {
          break;
        }
      if (count == size - 1)
        {
          size++;
          input = expand(input, size);
        }
      input[count] = *temp;
      count++;

    }

  int i;
  for (i=0; i<size - 1; i++)
    {
      if (i == size - 2)
        {
          fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", input[i]);
          break;
        }
      fprintf(stderr, "%d, ", input[i]);
    }


  free(input);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you know about the `realloc()` function?

The `realloc()` function will handle the posted scenario without any copying of the data. (the interior of the realloc() function handles the copying, if needed.